# Parsear html con JQUERY

Tags: html, jquery, parser

A partir de la tabla que muestro a continuación, alguien me podría decir como guardar en una variable el valor de la tabla perteneciente a 'REGISTRO' en JQUERY?
Es decir que dependiendo del valor de REGISTRO, que puede ser SI o NO, guardar eso en una varibale para utilizar más adelante.

```
<table id="info-table" class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>

    <tr class="active">
        <td>VALOR</td>
        <td>
            152
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="active">
        <td>REGISTRO</td>
        <td>
            No
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si tu tabla es fija, según dices, entonces puedes valerte de su id y buscar directamente el valor del segundo `td` de la última fila: `var tdDato=$('#info-table tr:last td:eq(1)').text(); console.log(tdDato);`

Answer (score 0):

En caso de que solo necesites una vez el valor lo más fácil es darle una id al td y después recogerla con Jquery.

```
   <table id="info-table" class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>

        <tr class="active">
            <td>VALOR</td>
            <td>
                152
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="active">
            <td>REGISTRO</td>
            <td id="registro">
                No
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>


var registro = $('#registro').text();
```

En caso de hacerlo sin id tendrías que buscar el tr que necesitas y coger el texto del td.

```
$("td:contains('REGISTRO')").next().text();
```

o

```
$("td:contains('REGISTRO')").parent().children('td:nth-child(2)');
```

Comment: Alguna manera sin darle un id? Porque no puedo modificar el html...

Answer (score 0):

Si tu tabla es fija, según dices, entonces puedes valerte de su `id` y buscar directamente el valor del segundo `td` de la última fila con algo así: `$('#info-table tr:last td:eq(1)').text();`

La ventaja que tendría hacerlo así es que te evitas tener que recorrer toda la tabla en busca de un valor.

Nótese que también he aplicado `trim`, para que limpie los espacios sobrantes en el valor que recuperará en el `td`.

He aquí un código de prueba:

```js
var tdDato = $('#info-table tr:last td:eq(1)').text().trim();
console.log(tdDato);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-nn4HPE8lTHyVtfCBi5yW9d20FjT8BJwUXyWZT9InLYax14RDjBj46LmSztkmNP9w" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table id="info-table" class="table table-bordered pure-table">
  <tbody>

    <tr class="active">
      <td>VALOR</td>
      <td>
        152
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="active">
      <td>REGISTRO</td>
      <td>
        No
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Espero que sea de utilidad.