# Guardar contenido <iframe> en jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

Necesito guardar el contenido del siguiente código:

```
"<iframe src='info/info_template'></iframe>";
```

Lo que quiero, en jquery, es coger el html que hay en src=info/info_template y guardarlo en una variable, ya sea en html o en texto, me da igual.

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: Hiciste dos preguntas muy parecidas ayer, [en una](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/177777/250) obtuviste varias respuestas, [la otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/177787/250) la [respondí con algo que debería servirte](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/177799/250), ¿no te funcionó? ¿tuviste problemas al implementarla? Si las respuestas en las otras preguntas no te sirven, deberías dejar comentarios aclarando por qué no te sirven para que la gente pueda ayudarte en lugar de crear nuevas preguntas parecidas. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento general del sitio

Answer (score 1):

Si el iframe está en el mismo dominio, como parece ser el caso, imaginemos que tu documento dice:

```
<iframe id="el_iframe" src="info/info_template"></iframe>
```

En ese caso puedes capturar el contenido HTML como:

```
var iframeDocument = document.getElementById('el_iframe').contentDocument;
var iframeHTML = iframeDocument.body.innerHTML;
```

o bien

```
var iframeText = iframeDocument.body.innerText;
```

Si no te funciona `contentDocument` puedes probar usando

```
var iframeDocument = document.getElementById('el_iframe').contentWindow.document;
```

**EDIT:**

Si el iframe o su fuente están definidos en una variable al estilo:

```
var info = "<iframe src='info/info_template'></iframe>";
```

Puedes seguir el flujo antes descrito insertando el iframe en tu página. Te dejé un plunkr con el ejemplo:

https://plnkr.co/edit/QVLk3BV7mptzQ01cybqp?p=preview

**EDIT2**

Lo anterior se puede hacer perfectamente con ajax (te dejé [otro plunkr de ejemplo](https://plnkr.co/edit/lbqoNhtDeI5KoB3kfgG1?p=preview))

```
var info = '<iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>';
var iframe_url=jQuery(info).attr('src');

jQuery.ajax({
            method: 'get',
            url: iframe_url,
            dataType: 'html'
        }).then(function (iframeHTML) {
            document.getElementById('editor').innerText = iframeHTML;
            document.getElementById('iframe_html').innerHTML = escapaHTML(iframeHTML);
        });
```

Al usar este enfoque el contenido te llega completo: `<html>...</html>` en vez de sólo el contenido del `body`.

Ten en cuenta que un llamado ajax es asíncrono. En el ejemplo, todo lo que quieras hacer con la respuesta de la petición debe ocurrir dentro del bucle definido por `.then(function(iframeHTML) { .... });`. Afuera del bucle no existe la variable `iframeHTML` y aunque la asignaras a una variable global, no estará definida correctamente antes de que la promesa se resuelva.

(una excepción a esto sería usar async/await + babel, pero en serio, en serio, no vamos a entrar en ese tema en esta respuesta)

## Ojo

si quieres usar el contenido HTML del iframe, y tratarlo como texto (por ejemplo ponerlo en un elemento `<pre>` para mostrar el código fuente) tienes que escapar el contenido, por ejemplo reemplazando  `<` por `&lt;` y          `>` por `&gt;`. Hay otros caracteres que no debieras meter en un textarea sin escapar, pero creo que está fuera del alcance de esta pregunta. Esto te lo digo porque si insertas el HTML del iframe, su contenido se aplica a la página principal. Los scripts no se ejecutan, pero los estilos, por ejemplo, sí se aplican si no los escapas:

El iframe tiene un estilo que define `font-weight:bold;` en todo el documento. Si dice:

```
document.getElementById('iframe_html').innerHTML = escapaHTML(iframeHTML);
```

Pusieras en cambio:

```
document.getElementById('iframe_html').innerHTML = iframeHTML;
```

Esto provocaría que la importación del contenido del iframe afectara el estilo del documento principal.

Comment: Esto funcionaría si estuviera el <iframe> en el mismo código. Pero yo lo tengo así: var info = "<iframe src='info/info_template'></iframe>";
Está así dentro de cñodigo jquery. Solución?

Comment: Bueno... una opción sería insertarlo haciendo `jQuery(info).attr('id','el_iframe').appendTo('body')` y ya lo tienes en tu documento. Voy a editar la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar $.get

```
$.get('info/info_template', function (data) {
    // data contains your html
});
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203502/jquery-load-to-variable)

Comment: Me da error, esto lo hago en medio de un script, puede venir el fallo por ahí? Necesito ese valor dentro de un script y dentro de un for.

Comment: ¿Que fallo te da?

Comment: Si lo hago como tu, me imprime todo el valor de data, pero no el de ese get, sino el de otro (lo estoy haciendo dentro de otro igual). 
Pero si lo hago asi:
    var dt;
    $.get('info/info_template', function (data) {
        // data contains your html
        dt = data;
    })

Así me imprime undefined. Alguna solución?

Comment: ¿el del otro? No entiendo a que te refieres.

Comment: Donde hago lo que me has dicho, el código ya está dentro de otra function(data) de un $.ajax

Comment: Cambia el nombre del data del $.get

Comment: Ya he probado y así no me imprime nada.

Comment: ¿como lo has impreso?

Comment: Pues normal, creo, como debería hacerlo?

Comment: Con un alert deberia imprimirtelo.

Comment: Pues no me imprime nada, es como si ese trozo de código no hiciera nada.

Comment: Me gusta esta solución, abarca el hecho de evitar la problemática de estar dentro o fuera del dominio la url, contemplando, claro está, que usa jquery, algo que doy por hecho porque usó la que hizo la pregunta la etiqueta.